# Azure Data Factory outbound data transfer pricing

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to use Azure Data Factory V2 to copy data from Blob Storage to another Blob Storage. Two Blob storage are the same region and Data Factory is different region.

So outbound data transfer will be charged or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bandwidth refers to data moving in and out of Azure data centers.

**Data going out of Azure data centres are charged as follows:**

[image]

Use of the copy activity to egress data out of an Azure datacenter will incur additional network bandwidth charges, which will show up as a separate outbound data transfer line item on your bill. [More information](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/bandwidth/).

Comment: Thank for your answer, as my understand, If I use Data Factory to copy data between 2 Blob storage with the same region then I will not have any additional data transfer costs although region of Data Factory is different from 2 Blob storage, is it right ?

Comment: There are no transaction costs in addition to standard storage transaction costs when importing data into Azure Storage. The standard egress charges are applicable when data is exported from Blob storage.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but my question is about region. For example I have 2 Azure Blob Storage:
Blob Storage 1: Japan East.
Blob Storage 2: Japan East.
Data Factory service: Southeast Asia.
When I use Data Factory to copy data from Blob Storage 1 to Blob Storage 2, I will have additional data transfer costs or not ?

Comment: Azure Storage in the same region will not have any additional data transfer costs.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Factory charges you in a variety of modes as below based on your integration runtime. 
How ever, when your Copy Activity moves data with a same data center. You will not be charged for that. (DIU's count is not considered for billing)
Pipeline activities: $0.005/hour**